# how to find the line break in my text file?

Tags: line-breaks

I have a text file sent from our customer. The line break in this text file is not CRLF, CR or LF since when I open it using notepad, there is no line, everything is just together. If I open it using word, or VS, I could see the lines. Can anyone tell me how to find out what is the line break in such a file?

Comment: use a hex editor. that'll show EXACTLY what chars are in use. and don't use notepad. It's useful for quick/dirty text edits, but utterly useless for anything serious, especially if you're using cross-platform text files.

Comment: Thank. I opened it with hex editor in VS. I notice each line is end up with 09 0A, do you know what does it mean?

Comment: http://www.ascii-code.com/  look up the hex codes there, but `0x09` is horizontal tab, and `0x0a` is line feed.

Answer (score 1):

Usually LF break works like this.

In Windows I open it using Notepad++ and choose "show hidden symbols"